# Device orientation start all view controller in tab bar app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

I have an app with a tab bar controller with 4 tab bar item , every tab bar item display a view controller and viewDidLoad start a query parse Method .
From first ios8 beta when the device ( or simulator ) change orientation the app launch all view controller viewDidLoad method and consequently start query parse Method in all view controller !
How can i stop this !

Where am I missing?

Thanks so much!

P.S. : Excuse for my terrible english ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the behavior going forward. You'll need to change you code to handle it. You'll have to move it to view will appear possibly with a bool/date to track when you last loaded your data.

You'd need to refactor something like this:

1. Create a BOOL property for the VC something like loadedData
2. Take your loading code from `viewDidLoad` and move it into `viewWillAppear:` wrapped in a check `if (!self.loadedData) { }`

Comment: could you give me an example or a guide?

Comment: I do not know if it can be useful, but I give one more detail: 
the tab bar controller is operated only through storyboards, does not have a custom class! 
How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Hi, this problems is still in iOS 8.1.3 version to this date.